# NameError in TodoConroller#add

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**app/controllers/todos_controller.rb**

```
def add
   todo = Todo.create(:todo_item => params[:todo_text])
   if !todo.valid?
        flash[:error] = todo.errors.full_messages.join("<br>").html_safe
   end
   redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

**Error Message**:

> NameError in TodosController#add undefined local variable or method
>   'todo' for #

How to solve these problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def add
  todo = Todo.create(:todo_item => params[:todo_text])
  if todo && !todo.valid? 
    flash[:error] = todo.errors.full_messages.join("").html_safe 
  end 
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```